# How can I use Gmap in Views Exposed filters

Tags: 7, views, location, google-maps

How can I use gmap in the view exposed filter ? So that user can search the result by marking the location on gmap.
I am using gmap 7.x-2.7 and location cck 7.x-3.0-rc2 .
How can I implement this functionality

Comment: Does the gmap module definitely have that functionality? Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: Hi Clive,Thanks No I did not find anything on google.Also I updated the issue summary

Comment: If the module doesn't have that functionality, you'll be best served submitting this as a feature request to the module issue queue. We can't really deal with it here, as it would fragment the support of that module in an undesirable way. Wait to see if you get any answers first though, on the off-chance that the functionality already does exist, and just isn't documented anywhere

Comment: question which is little much similar https://groups.drupal.org/node/36612

Comment: you are right clive.going to file support request.I will update issue summary after submitting the request

Comment: Do anyone know if it can be done by using https://www.drupal.org/project/openlayers ?